# ArrayAdapter<String> - string through WiFi socket, adding only one string, in updateUIThread

Tags: android, arrays, sockets, android-arrayadapter

I am configuring my socket server that receives messages from client app on another phone. Everything works great accept that list view is not adding incoming messages except the first one. I think it might be because my ArrayAdapter is in updateUIThread class:

```
class updateUIThread implements Runnable {

    private String msg;

    public updateUIThread(String str) {
        this.msg = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        listItems.add(msg);
    }
}
```

I am implementing Array in onCreate() like this:

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.in);
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This is the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="bottom" >

<ListView
android:id="@+id/in" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:stackFromBottom="true"
android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" 
android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

As I said, there is only one message on screen, maybe I should replace the UI Thread?
Just in case, there is full code exept declarations and onCreate():

```
class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            try {

                socket = serverSocket.accept();

                //Dopisane-----------
                 handler.post(new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                         status.setText("Połączono.");
                     }
                 });

                CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                new Thread(commThread).start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

    private Socket clientSocket;

    private BufferedReader input;

    public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {

        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

        try {

            this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            try {

                String read = input.readLine();

                updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
    private String msg;

    public updateUIThread(String str) {
        this.msg = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() { 
        listItems.add(msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didn't call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after updateUIThread->listItems.add(msg);

Comment: I love you brother, u r my new hero :D Thank You!